# Taking input a list and sorting it in the same line gives NoneType, why is that?

Tags: python

I am reading a list of integers separated by space and sorting them.

```
S = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]
S.sort()
```

Works fine, but when I do,

```
S = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")].sort(" ")
```

Or,

```
S = list(int(x) for x in input().split(" ")).sort(" ")
```

S gives a NoneType element, why is that? Aren't they both he same thing? I am taking input a list and sorting it.

Answer (score 2):

.sort() returns None, so the variable assignment ends up giving None. You're looking for this:

```
s = sorted(s)
```

sorted() returns the sorted list. .sort() sorts it in place.

Comment: understood, thanks!